# Posición del menú contextual

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

Trabajo en un proyecto escolar e intento hacer un menu contextual dentro de una ventana modal popup (los datos se cargan dinamicamente) que a su vez tiene una tabla dentro.
Mi problema radica en la posición en que se muestra el menú contextua, alguna idea de por que me sucede esto ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar no importa el renglón de la tabla donde de clic derecho el menú siempre se muestra en esa posición, Este es el código para el menú

HTML

```
<ul id="menuCapa" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"> 

<li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" onClick="restauraCapa();">Restaurar</a>
</li> 
<li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>

<li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" onClick="eliminaCapa();">Eliminar</a>
</li>
```

ASÍ MANDO LLAMAR LA FUNCIÓN QUE ACTIVA EL MENÚ

```
<tr class="abajo">
            <td>1</td>
            <td onMouseDown="menu(event)">El conocimiento escolar</td>
            <td>El conocimiento escolar</td>
            <td>Los alumnos desarrollaran recursos didacticos</td>
        </tr>
```

FUNCION JS

```
    function menu(event)
{
    $("#menuCapa").css("top", event.clientY);
    $("#menuCapa").css("left", event.clientX);
    $("#menuCapa").show('fast');    

}
```

DE ANTEMANO GRACIAS POR LA AYUDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me di cuenta que estas usando jQuery, por lo que no entiendo por que haces uso de la libreria si no la vas a utilizar como realmente es.

Uno de los problemas que veo es en tu función de JS, estas configurando el estilo del elemento #menuCapa pero deberías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#menuCapa".css("top", event.pageY + "px");
```

**¿Cuál es la diferencia entre pageX/Y y clienteX/Y?**

Bueno, una imagen vale más que mil palabras.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pageX/Y se relaciona desde la esquina superior izquierda de toda la página renderizada (incluyendo partes ocultas por el scroll).

Mientras clientX/Y se relaciona desde la esquina superior izquierda desde la parte visible de la página, lo que se ve desde el navegador.

---

Ahora, también tendriamos que ver como son los estilos del menu, ya que eso puede reflejar la manera en que el menu se muestra y sus acciones que se ejecutan.

---

Dejo un ejemplo que hice en codePen [aquí](https://codepen.io/Hoose/pen/RxeOLO).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var materiaSeleccionada;
  $( '#info-materias tbody tr' ).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.custom-menu').toggle(100).css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
    //Selecciono donde di clic para ejecutar una accion despues
    materiaSeleccionada = $(this);
  });
  
  $(".custom-menu li").click(function(){
    let action = $(this).attr('data-action');
    
    switch(action) {
        case "delete":
          $(materiaSeleccionada).remove();
        break;
        case "details":
          let nombreMateria = materiaSeleccionada.first().text();
          alert("Detalles de la materia " + nombreMateria);
        break;
    }
    // Esconder el menu después de la ejecución
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  });
  
  $(document).on("mousedown", function (e) {    
    // Si no se da clic al menu contextual
    if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
        // Escondelo
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.mt-2{
  margin-top:2em;
}

#info-materias {
  cursor:default;
}

.custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

.custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    user-select: none;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #DEF;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="info-materias">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Materia</th>
              <th>Tema</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Matematicas</td>
              <td>Ecuaciones</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Historia</td>
              <td>Revolución Mexicana</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Programación web</td>
              <td>Crear menu contextual</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>
        <ul class='custom-menu'>
          <li data-action="delete">Eliminar</li>
          <li data-action="details">Ver detalles</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la verdad es que soy nuevo en jquery  y   aun no termino por entenderlo del todo, lo hice de esa manera por que la tabla que  contiene  la venta modal se crea a partir de la base de datos y necesitaba pasar el id del elemento en donde dieron click por esa razon lo hice asi por que no se me ocurrió otra forma

Comment: No hay problema. Si la respuesta soluciono tu duda, marcala como correcta. Si tienes alguna otra duda, hazmela saber.